# Deploy to Azure websites / web jobs using certificates on the command line

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have multiple websites in Azure (Azurewebsites). Some have web jobs, some don't. One is an SPA app with minified JS and CSS.

We can do the packaging and building locally without any issues, but how to get the files across to Azure after we're done with that process?

I would like my deployment solution to have these properties:

1. Fully automated through the command line. No GUI or Visual Studio interaction at all.
2. Be able to clean out the destination directory. We have had trouble with stale configuration and binary files lying around after a refactor.
3. Without having any plain text passwords in any deployment configuration files
4. Preferably using an encrypted certificate to authenticate against Azure. We have a management certificate installed in Azure.
5. Preferably without using FTP, mostly because it's brittle to script
6. Preferably using the same base script for every project so I don't have to maintain four different ways of deploying to Azure.

I've looked at a bunch of options. Webdeploy seems most obvious but instructions on how to authenticate with certificate during deploy is hard to come by. Continous Delivery with git doesn't seem like a good idea: perhaps doable but the magic "we'll build everything from source for you and restore your packages and everything will be lollipops and unicorns" scares me a little (also it might require a major rework of our repository structure as we don't want every commit deployed. Is deployment only from some branches supported?). FTP could work but obviously requires plaintext passwords lying around. Those could be injected through the environment though.

This is a very easy operation when using a GUI but seems messy from the command line. Is there any equivalent to a unix-style "send an SSH command to remove all files then SCP this package over and unzip it"?

If not, what are the best options?

Answer (score 1):

We use WebDeploy/MSDeploy for 40+ products at work which includes deployments of web applications, services, SQL databases, scheduled tasks and more.  It can do everything your asking for except the cert based auth.

I understand the need to keep passwords secure.  There are couple of options that may help with this:

- If a person will be triggering these you could have them enter the password instead of reading from a file.
- You could write a small console app to read passwords from a database and initiate the deployment
- You could use environment variables on your build/deploy agent to store the passwords.
- I think the best option is to use the [azure-powershell cmdlets](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell).  In this method you would download publish settings (which includes an Azure management cert) and then use the [Publish-AzureWebsiteProject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn722468.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) cmdlet to deploy your WebDeploy package to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [ProjectKudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki)

This is the underlying mechanism within Azure that manages the deployment process. While there are standard scripts that manage the copy and deployment process all of these can be rewritten to deploy exactly what you need.

For instance, once the files have been copied to a holding directory, you can use xcopy to transfer what you need into wwwroot. I've never used it, but I suspect that del is also available.

You can also produce a custom build script if required. That would take care of any post processing.

In order to put the files there, it might be a solution to have a git repo that only has your deployments.

The whole project is open sourced, and you can configure a custom kudu installation to manage your deployment. So if you don't want to use git, it wouldn't be a difficult job to adjust the source code to pull your files from storage blobs if required.

For secrets you can either add them as environment variables, store them in keyvault for your deployment script to pick up (via Powershell etc) or for the kudu deployment script to collect.

I have only ever touched on the basics of what it can do, but it does seem a very flexible solution, that should solve all of your problems.